# Setting up postgres on VPS for production

Tags: postgresql, pyramid

So, I have a Pyramid app with a postgres database on my local machine. I did a pg_dump to get a dump of the data in my database, called pg_dump_2014-04-22. I then git pushed this file, and did a git pull in the VPS to get the file.

Now, I have already installed postgres on my VPS. When I `sudo -u postgres psql` on my VPS, I can connect to it but there are no relations (naturally).

Both my username and database name are `postgres`.

So, I tried `psql postgres < pg_dump_2014-04-22`, but this gives the error `psql: FATAL: role "root" does not exist`.

I also tried `pg_restore -h localhost -U postgres -d postgres pg_dump_2014-04-22`, and that prompts me for my password, but then throws the error `pg_restore: [archiver(db)] connection to database "postgres" falied: FATAL: password authentication failed for user postgres"`

What am I missing here?

Comment: (temporally) add a line `local postgres postgres trust` to your pg_hba.conf file.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to create a user and the database where you want to import your dump

`su postgres`

`createuser root`

`createdb yourdb`

Then import the dump with

`psql -d yourdb -f pg_dump_2014-04-22`

Comment: There is no need to create a `root` user in Postgres.

Comment: True but since he is trying to import ad root that's why I have included the user creation

Comment: It would be much better to simply provide the correct postgres username to `psql` using the `-U` option.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I have followed these steps but am getting an UTF-8 encoding error. (I think, actually it messed up the terminal's output in the VPS so I can't read it properly). Would something like this work? ``createdb mydb -E utf-8``

Comment: Give it a go. Since you're importing you can still drop and recreate the db

Comment: ok, I'll give it a try. The error earlier was actually ``invalid byte sequence for encoding “UTF8”``

Comment: I am still getting the invalid byte sequence error. There are some special characters in my data like è, α and β but doesn't UTF-8 include these characters? Oh and my locale is en_US.UTF-8.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487501/error-invalid-byte-sequence-while-restoring-postgresql-database) question.